# How to get Route name in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working with a **laravel 8** app, I want to get the route name which we write in the ->name() method. Basically want to print this name in title of page.

[->name() method in the laravel 8, Laravel Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPkbw.png)

`Route::view('/documents_for_approvals','document_approval')->name('Document Approvals'); //SA`

Comment: That's not the title though, that's the name of the route for easy access. Title should go into the view.

Comment: Do you want : `$request->route()->getName()`

Comment: I think this is not best approach for showing title from route name. You can use some alternative way like make constants for every page title, and show it from constants.
You can use anywhere inside laravel project PageTitles::HOME like this.
final class PageTitles{
    CONST HOME            =   'Home Page';
    CONST ABOUT_US   =   'About Us';}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View  :

```
{{Route::current()->getName()}}
```

If you want to show the current route name in the browser Tab foreach pages
add this to your layout view

```
<title>{{Route::current()->getName()}}</title>
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to project and open a command line and write the line below

```
php artisan route:list --path=documents_for_approvals
```

Update

[image]

Comment: That won't "_print this name in title of page_" though

Comment: Please take screenshot and send me

Comment: Screenshot of what? Btw, I'm not OP

Comment: The route name isn't to show in frontend it's to use it in code instead to write full route url

Comment: what on earth are you talking about esmail